# css fixed position on top within wrapper?

Tags: css, wrapper

I have a `#wrapper { margin: 0 auto }` centered in the middle. 
I want to align a `div.version` inside of that wrapper at the top right corner (of this wrapper). So the `.version` div should still be inside of the `#wrapper`.

Which position value do I have to use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `absolute` and `relative` positioning for your divs like this:

```
#wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position:relative;
 width:400px;
 background:green;
 clear:both;
 overflow:auto;
 height:100px;
}

.version {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:50px;
}
```

### [Check out the DEMO](http://jsbin.com/anuma3/2)

So, to make an element appear inside another element, you should give parent a position set to `relative` while any child element a position of `absolute` :)

Check out the nice article written on the subject at css-tricks.com:

- [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

[image]